# Router Access Control List

Tags: networking, router

I've always been taught that at the end of every network router access control list there is an implicit deny statement.

**Question:** In such instances if you want other traffic to pass through do you have to put a permit any statement or it will be blocked because of the implicit deny?

I just recently learned there are some routers that implicitly allow all traffic and you have to write deny statements for traffic you don't want to pass through.

I've tried to find information on these router ACL methods but haven't found anything so far. I'm hoping someone can provide some clarity for me on this topic.

Comment: The methodology I use in such instances is "*block everything and only allow thru what you need allow thru explicitly*".  I wouldn't worry about trying to find instances of routers that have implicit allow everything ACLs, etc. and would focus more on what you need to configure based on the defaults and such functionality of your make and model specific router.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard or specification according to which packet filtering configuration should be written. (And in general, the term 'access control list' applies to many other things besides network packet filters.)

You've been taught about *one specific implementation* of access control lists (I'm guessing Cisco IOS?); however, other products and implementations follow their own conventions – and some of them use "implicit allow", either for historical reasons, or because it makes unnecessary to have a separate "on/off" switch for filtering (the filter is always active, it just starts with no rules).

For example, [OpenBSD *pf*](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html) is documented to use implicit 'pass'. Linux *iptables* & *nftables* both have a [policy](https://serverfault.com/questions/189729/what-the-meaning-of-policy-accept-and-policy-drop-in-iptables) setting which is set to implicit "accept" by default, but can be changed to "drop". And [JunOS](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/general/policy-routing-policies-firewall-filters-comparison.html) firewall filters *apparently* are implicit-accept when they don't have any match rules yet, but become implicit-deny when you add some.

In addition to that, *user interfaces* might act differently than the underlying mechanism. For example, although pfSense just provides graphical configuration for the same *pf*, it always adds a hidden "block all" rule, resulting in apparent implicit-deny even though under the hood it's explicit.

Answer (score -1):

Generally by default for any consumer level firewall, the outgoing connections are allow by default, with implicit denying.

Most users don't want to stop traffic going out from their network (knowingly at least) so the default makes sense for the most people and is easiest to configure this way.

Comment: Why are you answering this non-question? This should be a comment.